# @types folder is not being compiled with tsc

Tags: typescript, tsc

I have a `src` folder which contains all my `.ts` and `.d.ts` files, according to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) all visible `@types` folders should be included in the compilation, but whenever I run `npx tsc`, the folder is not being compiled.

`src` folder:

[image]

`build` folder:

[image]

Finally, I have two `tsconfig` file, one extends from the other:

- tsconfig.base.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "tests/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

- tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tests/**/*.test.ts",
    "dist"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38146) issue is relevant. Existing .d.ts files don't seem to be copied to the output folder